# How to create a dynamic web api client in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, client, data-access-layer, apiclient

I developed an ASP.Net web api with about 80 different api calls.

I would like to create a dynamic web api client, allowing the application code to remain simple and the "web api client layer" to be reusable (without the need of creating 80 different methods).

I would expect the web api client to look something like this:

```
public dynamic WebApi(string method, params object[] list)
{
     // Setting the api request by the input...
     // Calling the web api...
     // Handling the results...
}
```

I'd expect the apps using it to look something like this:

```
List<Stations> stations = WebApi("GetStationsByCompany", companyId);
```

Now i feel like this is a very common use case so i shouldn't be developing it myself, however i couldn't find any examples for this scenario online (for .Net Framework).

How should i create a dynamic web api client?
What is the best practice for it?

Comment: It is a common problem but what you are describing is an _anti-pattern_ because  **1)** clients never know what `operations` are available **2)** clients never know what `parameters are expected` **3)** the server doesn't know what `parameters are legitimate` **4)** the code suffers from a lack of `type safety`  **5)** any refactoring performed will break the code - though you won't know until runtime

Comment: If you don't want to craft the client proxies by hand, you can code-generate them via _T4 Templates_

Comment: Good points, so the solution is to create 80 different client methods?

Comment: You could, but when faced with this problem I code-generate them via T4 as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to not to do the repetitive task of making client API, I would suggest you try NSwag tools of swagger which has a great facility to accomplish it. 
Also, I think that there isn't any way to a dynamic proxy that you mentioned.